# Should not be able to mark question as duplicate and link to own answer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, duplicate-questions

I just asked a question on Stack Overflow that was marked as a duplicate.  I don't agree but if I had more knowledge I wouldn't be asking questions in the first place.  Either way the person who marked it a duplicate referenced another question that *they* answered.  I couldn't understand the other question or the other answer.  So my comment is this: If you going to moderate something it shouldn't involve something else you've done.  A little separation of powers if that makes sense.

Comment: Well, the original authors are usually the best to know if their answers fit to answer your problem. If you aren't able to get the abstraction and extrapolate, it's probably not their problem, but yours. I've done that myself several times, and I can confirm that action usually doesn't result in any rep gain, and even if so, it wasn't my intend to do so.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21533/i-dont-think-its-right-to-mark-question-as-duplicate this is prob an even better idea.

Comment: Why so? Can you explain in depth please?

Comment: what is the point of this website?  it's to help people get answers they understand.  the question that I asked was thankfully answered by someone in a way I understand , barmar's answer did not.  if i understand one but not the other then naturally they are different enough that they should not be marked as the "exact same"

Comment: _"it's to help people get answers they understand"_ No, it's not about giving individual help, but being useful for future research as a FAQ like repository. If an individual isn't able to understand, there's probably more study needed to get on the with _the basics_.

Comment: yep, you're right, i'm wrong.  thanks

Comment: related: [Is the dupehammer (Mjölnir) still being evaluated, and if so, what is the current outcome?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298810/839601) "It's something we're always going to continue to keep an eye on, because it is quite a bit of power to wield. It's working very well in the hands of people that _currently_ have the ability.  

That said, we're calling it a _resounding_ success..."

Answer (score 6):

I don't have the domain knowledge required to tell whether or not it is a dupe, but...

I have to say that I trust that Barmar does (I'm assuming that that's who this is about). I also trust that he wouldn't forge a dupe for rep. He's a (very) established user of the community, and one that already has "all the rep he could ever need".

This highlights a problem with your suggestion: people answering such questions are the ones with the domain knowledge to tell if a question is a dupe or not.

If there was evidence of abuse, maybe, but I think this would be better left to a case-by-case basis. I've seen complaints about users abusing powers to get rep (answering a question, then force closing it to prevent other answers), but without widespread abuse, I can see restrictions, like those suggested, causing more harm than good.